# Can't make fence same on all sides With Geo Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

The problem is I can do the rotation on one side of the fence but can't on both together Andy if done only once One of those sides become as 2nd image. There a lot [Project Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dG053CL1VW1-MIjJXJ9zyU7bPVpgqVmu/view?usp=sharing) more improvements to be made but I am right now stuck here.

[image]

The Fence I tried to make using Geometry Using Geometry nodes with this nodes setup Below But the problem was Though I was able to  create the fences on one sides clear I can't make them on both sides I used The Rotation for each Instance which are a set of fences vertical series.

[image]

First from two curve lines I created a set of joins, then converted them into a mesh, Using a Curve line's point I created a vertical setting for them and then using set of them to be instanced onto the Plane's points at some length.
But they don't look like a fence on each side so I needed to do some rotations for that instance in which I checked it's position and changed it's rotation by doing addition and multiplication of both of the values so that the final result only gives me some rotation onto some nodes only.
[Project Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dG053CL1VW1-MIjJXJ9zyU7bPVpgqVmu/view?usp=sharing)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your node tree image is not readable

Comment: Maybe a better approach is to create a flat fence (an area) and then UV project it with the *Sample UV Surface* node on a cube or whatever you want =>https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc5Lh.jpg.